# Teste de Integração .Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, testes, testes-automatizados

Estou criando um teste de integração utilizando o tuto da microsoft [Integration tests in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

```
public class WebAppFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // Create a new service provider.
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            // Add a database context (ApplicationDbContext) using an in-memory 
            // database for testing.
            services.AddDbContext<AsiaCabIdentityContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
                options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
            });

        });
    }
}
```

Esta é a minha classe de teste

```
public class IntegrationTest : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

    public IntegrationTest(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>();
    }


    [Fact]
    public void Teste_Ok()
    {

        // Arrange
        var httpClient = _factory.CreateClient();


        var result = httpClient.GetAsync("/api/v1/user").Result;
    }
}
```

Quando tento executar o teste recebo este erro :

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>     HResult=0x80131604
>     Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>     Source=System.Private.CoreLib
>     StackTrace:
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderFactory.WebHostFactoryResolver.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`2.<ResolveWebHostBuilderFactory>b__0(String[] args)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateWebHostBuilder()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureServer()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient(WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions options)
>      at Identity.Tests.Integration.PageTest.Teste_Ok() in C:\test\Identity.Tests\Integration\PageTest.cs:line 22

Inner Exception 1:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.

Já instalei o Kestrel no framework

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="2.2.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.10.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Bogus" Version="27.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.console" Version="2.4.1">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive um problema parecido, porém ele acusava não encontrar a lib Microsoft.AspNetCore.App. Oque eu fiz para resolver foi adicionar o import dessa lib no meu csproj.

Então no seu caso, eu tentaria adicionar:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.2.0" />
```